# Is it safe to put database file in htdocs?

Tags: apache, webserver

Gudeve,

Can you recommend me a directory in my web server where I should put sensitive files?
My htdocs is arranged like this:

```
XAMPP/htdocs/NewsFeed
```

The NewsFeed directory have index.php. The index.php file's function is to connect to a database. Now, should I put the database file inside htdocs? Will it be safe?

Comment: What do you mean with "database file"?

Comment: Sounds like s/he wants to put something like an Access .mdb file there and then have a web app connect to it.

Comment: does your webhost allow you to place files outside of the webroot htdocs folder?  ...not all do apparently.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a chance to keep it outside then I suggest you to keep outside. If it is protected, a vulnerability may be exploited even at a later time causing some intrusions. So please try to keep it "away"

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are using a SQLite database. I do not think putting it in `htdocs` is a safe, unless you safeguard it (maybe with .htaccess / `chmod`) in such a way that the database cannot be accessed by `others`/`world`.

Answer (score 1):

Database and database connection details (login, password etc.) should be kept outside htdocs directory.

For editing purposes only you can obfuscate the password, have a look at this post: [Don’t let them see your MySQL password](http://developingmadness.com/blog/2009/05/10/don%E2%80%99t-let-them-see-your-mysql-password/)

Comment: I don't see how the advice in that article will help Keira Nighly.   ...did I miss something?

Comment: I don't see reason for downvoting when next to direct answer there is information on very similar subject.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put a database file anywhere it can be web accessible.  One should *not* be able to download your database over HTTP, and if it's web accessible, anyone will be able to do this.

This ought not be confused with connecting to your database.  That's something your script will do.

Place the database in some server directory that is only accessible locally (to the webserver), by your script.  ie.  XAMPP/db